# Removing Public from URL but allow 'Publications'

Tags: php, .htaccess, laravel, laravel-4

I know this question has been asked a million times, but bear with me here. I use an .htaccess file at the base directory of my local server with:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On

    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /public/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

This works great, but only one problem. If I put anything with 'public' in the first URL parameter, it gives me a 404.

So if I have `www.test.dev/publications`, it 404's me because it has 'public' in the name. I've tested thoroughly to make sure it was an HTACCESS issue and it definitely is. If I name the route `www.test.dev/publi`, it works fine, same with `www.test.dev/publi-cations`.

Does anyone have any ideas here to allow publications inside the URL with an .htaccess file?

Thanks!

EDIT: Just thought I should let you know that yes this isn't the right way to go about removing public from the URL, but my company refuses to change host and I don't have access to modify the site root.

/public/.htaccess

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
<IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
    Options -MultiViews
</IfModule>

RewriteEngine On

# Redirect Trailing Slashes...
RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]

# Handle Front Controller...
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: What errors you get, it works with `http://blog.dev/publications` from my localhost (`blog` is my folder name).

Comment: I just get a basic 404 not found, I'm using Route::get('publications/reports', 'PublicationsController@reports'); and still gives me 404. If I remove the .htaccess file and do www.test.dev/public/publications/reports it works fine

Answer (score 0):

Try this in `.htaccess`, it works with `http://blog.dev/publications` from my `localhost`

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>

    <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
        Options -MultiViews
    </IfModule>

    RewriteEngine On

    # Redirect Trailing Slashes...
    RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]

    # Handle Front Controller...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: This only works if I modify my virtual hosts to make the base directory 'public'. This is the correct way I understand, but my production server host doesn't allow the modification of the base directory on the server.

Comment: Then, you have to find an ugly heck, IMO.

Answer (score 0):

To remove the `/public/` part of your urls, you don't have to add `/public/` to your `.htaccess`, you need to point your `VirtualHost DocumentRoot` directly to that folder, this is an example:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName yourdomain.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/yourdomain.com/public

    <Directory /var/www/yourdomain.com>
        Options Indexes Includes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
        AllowOverride AuthConfig FileInfo
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

And then just have something like this in your .htaccess:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
        Options -MultiViews
    </IfModule>

    RewriteEngine On

    # Redirect Trailing Slashes...
    RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]

    # Handle Front Controller...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: I can edit the virtual host locally on my PC to point to the public folder, but I can't on the production server, so I have to find a solution with some .htaccess file.

Comment: What kind of hosting doesn't let you access to change the document root? Most of them will give you a panel to do that, this is an example from a Parallels Panel: http://puu.sh/6E431.png

Answer (score 0):

Try this rule:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^((?!public/).*)$ /public/$1 [L,NC]
```

**UPDATE:** Suggested `/public/.htaccess`:

```
Options -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /public/

# Redirect Trailing Slashes...
#RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]

# Handle Front Controller...
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule . index.php [L]
```

Comment: Nah still doesn't work, get a 404. Thanks so much for the answer though!

Comment: For which URL you're getting 404 now?

Comment: www.test.dev/publications/reports, if I rename the route to www.test.dev/publi/reports OR www.test.dev/publi-cations/reports it works fine. I need to be able to use publications in the URL as that's the regulations in my office unfortunately

Comment: Is `publications` a directory? If yes then s there any .htaccess in it? Are there more rules in this .htaccess?

Comment: No publications is a controller and reports is a method, there is no other .htaccess besides the one in root folder that I'm working with now to remove 'public' from my URL's

Comment: And is this the only rule OR there are other rules also?

Comment: The rule you gave me is the only thing inside the htaccess file

Comment: If you comment this rule then what happens? Are you sure tht public directory has no .htaccess?

Comment: The public directory has the htaccess that ships with laravel

Comment: Ok can you post that `public/.htaccess` in your question?

Comment: added it to the question, also sorry, accidentally invited you to a chat

Comment: Hmm don't see much wrong there. Can you try UPDATE section.

Comment: No dice, still 404. I ended up just renaming the public folder to public_html and then modified my original htcaccess (in my question) for that folder. It now works fine but not sure how deployment will go with it named that.

Comment: Hmm that's sad. From mod_rewrite We tried everything but I don't know laravel routing mechanism so some weirdness is suspected there.